# Float right div with padding for wordpress header.php?

Tags: css, wordpress, html, css-float

I am trying to get a few lines of text under my li menu. I want it to float right with padding. Also, for some reason it is way to far down below my menu and too far right. This happened when I tried just using

```
<div style="float: right;">
```

I am going to put it in my wordpress header.php

I am not an HTML or CSS coder. I use wordpress themes and I pull out CSS that I like from the web and then I change it up using firebug. This [annmariedavis.com](http://annmariedavis.com/) comes from a child theme that I modified.

Comment: Could you show more of the css? It's most likely because the div is positioned relative to the other content on the page and is getting "pushed" down from the other elements.

Comment: Are you sure floating positioning is what you're looking for?
Perhaps fixed positioning instead? It would be easier if you'd explain a bit what you're looking for. Check out [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ybWW3/5/) to see how fixed positioning works.

Answer (score 0):

add `<div style="float: right; width: 323px;">some text</div>` before `</nav>` or right after it, depends on where you want text to be located above or below line